# Simple Fancybox not working, following instructions to a tee. Please see my code

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox

I can't get Fancybox to work. I've read the instructions on the fancybox site a million times and it just doesn't work. My image loads as if it would without fancybox. Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox();
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
    <a href="img/test.jpg"><img src="img/test.jpg" /></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Plain HTML or is this in WordPress or something else?  Is your fancybox in the root folder?  Are you using jQuery for anything else on the page?  Anything else not showing up or working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check fancybox href attribute and src attribute they point to root so you need to remove the first slash /

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

Comment: wouldn't that only matter if his site is not in the root folder?  Might have just removed his domain from the example.

Comment: and add `class="fancybox"` to the link like @dani said

Comment: This was it! Thanks so much. I was also missing the class in my example but I had it in my version. The problem was the path. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Add class="fancybox" to the *a* tag.
Like this:

```
<a href="img/test.jpg" class="fancybox"><img src="img/test.jpg" /></a>
```

You're using *$('.fancybox')*, which makes jQuery look for fancybox class.